# Fit code/image inside my table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good evening everyone! I am having a bit of a problem and need some advice or assistance.  I designed a site in Photoshop, sliced it and exported it out as HTML/Images.  I brought the HTML file into Dreamweaver, this is what I have and it is great.

View the slice here.

[click here](http://japanesefriend.zxq.net/test.html)!

My problem is, I am trying to get some JavaScript/Jquery code inside those empty white boxes you see in the link above.  [click here](http://japanesefriend.zxq.net/test_page.html)! But when I try to put the images in my layout from the above link, my layout gets completely realigned and I cant seem to fix it and looks like this [click here](http://japanesefriend.zxq.net/test_page2.html)!

I give my sincere thanks to anyone who can offer any assistance or advice on this matter!

Comment: i suggest you hand code the markup and style, albeit time consuming, you've got full control

Comment: It isn't entirely clear what you are actually trying to do.   Though I agree with the other posters here, you may not have the skills to hand code the HTML.  I would just make sure whatever images you put in the TD's have the exact dimensions of those td's and that you specify them like `<img src="/images/test_31.jpg" width="212" height="228" />`  The second td has different dimensions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your first problem is outputting a sliced Photoshop file for web. It does it horribly and you should really just do it yourself.

Secondly, you need to make sure all your widths and heights are the same when putting in an image in that blank spot.

But really, you should just redo the code of it all.. using images for text is a no no. Your whole site could basically be done in HTML/CSS instead of with images.

Comment: Ok, I will have to improve my CSS and editing skills.  Thanks for the good advice !